# $K$-homology of $BG$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $G$ be a finite group.  Atiyah proved that the $K$-cohomology of $BG$ vanishes in odd degrees and in even degrees is the completion of the representation ring of $G$ at the augmentation ideal.

What is the $K$-homology of $BG$?  I mean the stable homotopy groups of the complex $K$-theory spectrum smash $BG$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In "$K$-homology of universal spaces and local cohomology of the representation ring" Greenlees proves that 
$$
K_i(BG_+) \simeq H_J^i(R(G))
$$
for $i=0,1$, where $J$ is the augmentation ideal and $H_J^i(R(G))$ refers to [local cohomology.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_cohomology) In fact Greenlees proves something more general using equivariant homotopy theory (for which the above is a special case), and this more general object is also studied in Chapter 18 of Greenlees and May's "Generalized Tate Cohomology"

Equivalently, one can use Anderson's universal coefficient theorem for $K$-theory (see  [here](http://faculty.tcu.edu/gfriedman/notes/Anderson-UCT.pdf)). Anderson shows that if $G$ is even a compact connected Lie group that $KU_1(BG) = 0$ and $$KU_0BG = \operatorname{lim}_n\operatorname{Hom}(R(G)/J^n,\mathbb{Z}).$$

There is a discussion of the relationship between the two results in Remark 2.8 of "Topological $K$-(co)homology of classifying spaces of discrete groups", by Joachim and  Lück (which also contains more results along these lines).

Comment: Thanks Drew.  I thought K_i(BG+) depends only on the parity of i.  Is that also true for H^i_J(RG)?

Comment: The $K$-homology groups are two-periodic. I think Greenlees' formula only holds for $i=0,1$, but then you can just use the periodicity. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Does H^2_J(R(G)) and higher vanish?

Comment: I believe not. By the Joachim and Lück paper the $n$-th local cohomology groups can identified with a colimit of $\text{Ext}^n$'s

Comment: @KHBG: yes, if $G$ is finite then $R(G)$ has Krull dimension one and so $H^k_J(M)=0$ for any $k>1$ and any $R(G)$-module $M$; see Chapter 6 of Brodmann and Sharp, for example.

Comment: Interesting! Apologies for the misinformation @KHBG

Answer (score 3):

For finite-type torsion spectra $X$ there is a natural isomorphism 
$$ KU_{n-1}(X) \simeq \text{Hom}_c(KU^n(X),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}). $$
Here $\text{Hom}_c$ denotes the group of homomorphisms that are continuous with respect to the skeletal topology on $KU^*(X)$ and the discrete topology on $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.  The isomorphism can be obtained in a fairly straightforward way using $X\wedge S\mathbb{Q}=0$ (so $X=\Sigma^{-1}X\wedge S(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$) and standard exactness arguments.

If $G$ is a finite group then we can take $X$ to be $\Sigma^\infty BG$ (without disjoint basepoint) to get reduced $K$-homology groups $KU_{2n}(BG)=0$ and
$$ KU_{2n-1}(BG) = \text{Hom}_c(\widehat{J}(G),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}). $$
Here $J(G)$ is the augmentation ideal in the representation ring, and $\widehat{J}(G)$ is the completion of $J(G)$ with respect to itself.  If $G$ is a $p$-group then we just have $\widehat{J}(G)=J(G)\otimes\mathbb{Z}_p$.

The above answer is of course the same as you get via local cohomology, but this argument is more elementary.